# Android Speech Recognition not working

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I'm using this example from newboston and it prompt me for recording but after it recognized what I said, it won't update the list view.

Here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int RECOGNIZER_RESULT = 1234;
ListView list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Button btn_speach = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
    btn_speach.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech to search");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RECOGNIZER_RESULT);

        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == RECOGNIZER_RESULT && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
        for(int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++){
            Log.i("MainActivity", matches.get(i));
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is the xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_speak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I do not get any errors. And the following code does not print anything in LogCat either.

```
for(int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++){
            Log.i("MainActivity", matches.get(i));
}
```

And I'm testing on my android device which has Speech Recognition functionality.

Comment: Hope here this blog will help you in engineering depth into the voice recognition problem http://blog.contus.com/how-to-implement-the-voice-recognition-functionality-in-android-devices/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code .. it is running in my app...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button speak;
    ListView options;
    ArrayList<String> results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //doctory endsl...
        speak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpeak);
        options = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOptions);

        speak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // This are the intents needed to start the Voice recognizer
                Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
               // i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                     //   RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 15); // number of maximum results..
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something");

                startActivityForResult(i, 1010);
            }
        });

        // retrieves data from the previous state. This is incase the phones
        // orientation changes
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            results = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("results");


            if (results != null) {
                options.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // retrieves data from the VoiceRecognizer
        if (requestCode == 1010 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            results = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            if (results.contains("close"))
            {
                finish();
            }//extra testing...
            options.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, (results));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // This should save all the data so that when the phone changes
        // orientation the data is saved
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putStringArrayList("results", results);
    } 

}
```

and xml is...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvOptions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSpeak"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Speak" />
```