# how to make google speech recognizer API android run faster?

Tags: android

I used method **Intent** and **SpeechRecognizer** but it very slow translate from speech to text, it took than 30s but something it faster about 3s. How to make it faster same same voice search of google? thanks you reading!

This is example code:

**Method Intent**

```
 package com.example.android.apis.app;
 import com.example.android.apis.R;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 /**
  * Sample code that invokes the speech recognition intent API.
  */
 public class VoiceRecognition extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private ListView mList;

/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);

    // Get display items for later interaction
    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() != 0) {
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    } else {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }
}

/**
 * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
 */
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
}

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
 }
```

**Method SpeechRecognizer**

```
package voice.recognition.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.util.Log;



public class voiceRecognitionTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

   private TextView mText;
   private SpeechRecognizer sr;
   private static final String TAG = "MyStt3Activity";
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);     
            mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
            sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());        
   }

   class listener implements RecognitionListener          
   {
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
            }
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
            }
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
            }
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
            }
            public void onEndOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
            }
            public void onError(int error)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
                     mText.setText("error " + error);
            }
            public void onResults(Bundle results)                   
            {
                     String str = new String();
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
                     ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                     for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
                     {
                               Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
                               str += data.get(i);
                     }
                     mText.setText("results: "+String.valueOf(data.size()));        
            }
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
            }
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
            }
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
                     sr.startListening(intent);
                     Log.i("111111","11111111");
            }
   }
}
```

Comment: Voice search depends on your network connection in general. If the connection is ok, it can be pretty fast. Share more details: which code is so slow?

Comment: you can check it without implementing the listener. why are you customizing it..see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770742/android-speech-recognition-not-working/23931004#23931004

Comment: @Nepster This works out for me, as by digging I found the another link interlinks on the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564561/does-the-google-speech-recognizer-on-android-need-internet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean/17674655#17674655