# How to convert speech to text during call with different text colors for caller and call receiver?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I want to convert speech to text during call. I also want the text to display in different colors: the call initiator's in red and the call receiver's green.

During my tests, I converted speech to text during call but was unable to distinguish between the voice of the call initiator and that of the call receiver.

Thanks in advance
Please Help me out...

Comment: see my answer here speech to text ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770742/android-speech-recognition-not-working/23931004#23931004

Comment: how can you convert speech to text during call ?.  what api did you used? please help me it's very urgent

Comment: You can use Bluemix Speech to text API during call and store the converted text in database.API link https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk @user1517638

Comment: Thanks for your response Pankaj. After i implement this speech to text into my code. Not working both simultaneously, either VOIP call (SInch API) working or speech to text (Bluemix API) working . Because android device mic can listen only one API at a time. can you please help me to fix this issue

Comment: come here and describe your issue http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidians @user1517638